# How to decompose my sparse Matrix using SVDLIBC...?

Tags: scala, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, text-mining

I am new to SVDLIBC. I tried to decompose a sample sparse matrix but it is not getting loaded, but throwing an error instead.

I also tried the mentioned SVDLIBC example of a sparse matrix.
Its throwing following error:

> praveen@praveen-Aspire-4739Z:~/Downloads/SVDLIBC$ ./svd -r st -w sth
>       Sample Loading the matrix...
>       Computing the SVD... SOLVING THE [A^TA] EIGENPROBLEM .....
>       NUMBER OF LANCZOS STEPS = 3 RITZ VALUES STABILIZED = 3
>       SINGULAR VALUES FOUND = 3 SIGNIFICANT VALUES = 3
>       ELAPSED CPU TIME = 0 sec. MULTIPLICATIONS BY A = 10 MULTIPLICATIONS BY A^T = 7

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer for the above question that I posted ...

In SVD it will create three matrix called S,U,V matrix. You can just run following command it will generate the matrix files:

```
./svd inputmatrix -o output
```